# Fossil crashing on commit with 'database is locked error'

Tags: version-control, fossil

I am looking for a Version Control tool for SQLite database. So on exploring I came to know about Fossil which is [recommended](https://sqlite.org/whynotgit.html) by SQLite also.

I am using latest version 2.7 for Windows and the problem I am facing is on using it in server mode and committing few files, it gets crashed frequently giving 'database is locked' error.

At first instance I thought that I am using the server and cloned copy on same system so it might be crashing due to this reason. But when I have started server on another system and even committing to it from a different system the result is same, It got crashed again.

Here's the screenshot of the crashed fossil server

[image]

Can anyone point me to the right direction that what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You might want to report this on [Fossil’s forum](https://fossil-scm.org/forum/). It may well have been fixed in the meantime; IME release version 2.7 was not a very solid release.

Comment: @Martijn Thanks for your suggestion. If that's the case I will try version 2.6 as well.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, version 2.7 still had some wrinkles with a newly added backoffice functionality.

In general, the backoffice processing can be turned off via setting `'fossil set backoffice-disable true'`, see help on [backoffice-disable](https://fossil-scm.org/index.html/help?cmd=backoffice-disable)

This would most likely resolve the issue you experienced.

Meanwhile, the recently released version 2.8 has those wrinkles resolved.